# XmlPullParserException in Android SOAP Webservices

Tags: android, web-services, soap, android-ksoap2

I want to consume soap webservices from andriod websevice program by using ksoap2. For that I have written the following code. When I run this in Android emulator I am not getting the response in my logcat. My webservices return type result is XML file .

```
public class SoapWebservicesExampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    final String NAMESPACE = "urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style";
    final String URL = "http://***********:8000/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/srvc_14DAE9C8D79F1EE196F1FC6C6518A345/wsdl11/allinone/ws_policy/document?sap-client=800&sap-user=*******&sap-password=*********";

//i am appending the Username and password as URL Parameters.

    final String METHOD_NAME = "Z_GET_CUST_GEN";
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style/Z_GET_CUST_GEN";

// i am getting the method name tns from WSDL file.

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); // set up
        request.addProperty("Input", "1460");
        //  request.addProperty("Langu", "d");

//one property in the webservices 

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); // put all required data into a soap
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        httpTransport.debug = true;
        try {
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

// by using call method we can call the services

            SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
            String str = response.getProperty(0).toString();
            System.out.println("theeeeeeeeeee"+str);

//printing the respose here

        }
        catch(SocketException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();

        } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

But here problem is I got  this exception i am adding ksoap2 jar file.

```
            05-29 15:37:54.403: WARN/System.err(383): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}wsdl:definitions targetNamespace='urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style'>@1:686 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40547218)
            05-29 15:37:54.403: WARN/System.err(383):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(KXmlParser.java:273)
```

Answer (score 0):

That means the property you are adding, i.e.

```
request.addProperty("Input", "1460");
```

is improper. Please check the web method that you are calling and make sure that the number of parameters, method name, spelling (that includes case too) of parameters are proper. I get this error all the time this is how you fix it.

((please share your web method too. if the above solution doesn't work))

Comment: thanks for ur reply my inputs is  <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <urn:Z_GET_CUST_GEN>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <Input>1460</Input>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <Langu>d</Langu>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <Max></Max>

Comment: Parameters "Langdu" and "Max" are not optional right? (I see optional thing commented). Anyway if they are not your add them as request.addProperty("param", object);

Comment: yes but my problem is not displaying anything in logcat but when i am tested in SoapUi pro it works fine and retun the xml output

Comment: Let's just add the two params and check if it works in the emulator.

Comment: wsdl url
http://***********:8000/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/srvc_14DAE9C8D79F1EE196F1FC6C6518A345/wsdl11/allinone/ws_policy/document?sap-client=800
input:-
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <urn:Z_GET_CUST_GEN>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <Input>1460</Input>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <Langu>d</Langu>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <Max></Max>
      </urn:Z_GET_CUST_GEN>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: binding url
http://************:8000/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/z_customer_lookup1/800/z_customer_lookup1/z_customer_lookup1_bind
output: - 
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>

Comment: Add the two params with dummy values and check if the error persists.

Comment: then paste the complete web method but just input type and output type.

Comment: sorry i have wsdl url from that i got the method name can i share my wsdl data?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <soap:Header/> 
    <soap:Body> <urn:Z_GET_CUST_GEN> 
    <!--Optional:--> 
    <Input>1460</Input> 
    <!--Optional:-->
     <Langu>d</Langu> 
    <!--Optional:--> 
    <Max></Max>
```

this is my input and output xml:

binding url

```
http://************:8000/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/z_customer_lookup1/800/z_customer_lookup1/z_customer_lookup1_bind
```

output: -

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <n0:Z_GET_CUST_GENResponse xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
         <ZCustGen>
            <item>
               <Kunnr>0000001460</Kunnr>
               <Name1>C.A.S. Computer Application Systems</Name1>
               <City>Dresden</City>
               <Land>DE</Land>
               <Pstlz>01187</Pstlz>
            </item>
            <item>
               <Kunnr>0000027182</Kunnr>
               <Name1>Johnson Food Center Inc.</Name1>
               <City>Rochester</City>
               <Land>US</Land>
               <Pstlz>14608</Pstlz>
            </item>
            <item>
               <Kunnr>0000301046</Kunnr>
               <Name1>Second Source</Name1>
               <City>ROCHESTER</City>
               <Land>US</Land>
               <Pstlz>14602</Pstlz>
            </item>
         </ZCustGen>
      </n0:Z_GET_CUST_GENResponse>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Set input to all value(langu,max) and you try.Whether u tried that.

Comment: see my out and input xml .how can i achive in Android

Comment: wsdl url
http://***********:8000/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/srvc_14DAE9C8D79F1EE196F1FC6C6518A345/wsdl11/allinone/ws_policy/document?sap-client=800

Comment: input:-
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <urn:Z_GET_CUST_GEN>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <Input>1460</Input>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <Langu>d</Langu>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <Max></Max>
      </urn:Z_GET_CUST_GEN>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: binding url
http://************:8000/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/z_customer_lookup1/800/z_customer_lookup1/z_customer_lookup1_bind
output: -

Comment: <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <n0:Z_GET_CUST_GENResponse xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
         <ZCustGen>
            <item>
               <Kunnr>0000001460</Kunnr>
               <Name1>C.A.S. Computer Application Systems</Name1>
               <City>Dresden</City>
               <Land>DE</Land>
            
               <Pstlz>14608</Pstlz>
            </item>

Comment: After u receiving that response did u parsing that xml.I think u r using Kxml parser for that.

Comment: no here i am not doing any parsing please send any samples or sugesstion to me to do that task ?

Comment: I don't have any tutorials about that.You just google it and you can get lots of tutorials based on that.